# Passing global pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers, types, struct

I declare a global struct Word *root = NULL; which I populate by using some pthread calls(created a BST) and when I go to print out an inorder traversal function by calling inorder(Word *root), it gives me an error saying "unexpected type name 'Word': expected expression". I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

```
void ordered(Word *root); // declaring function
//code//
Word *root = NULL; // declare global pointer to root

/*Main*/
//code that does some work and eventually creates a BST with root

ordered(Word *root); //call to my function
```

Comment: No need to specify variable type (`Word*` in your case) when calling a function. Just call `ordered(root);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these rules:

- You **must** specify the variable type when you declare the function
- You **may** specify the variable name when you declare the function
- You **must not** specify the variable type when you call the function

In your example, the variable type is `Word*` and the variable name is `root`.

So change this:

```
ordered(Word *root); //call to my function
```

To this:

```
ordered(root); //call to my function
```